# Does updating disabled services re-enable them?

Tags: fedora, yum, systemd, services

I remember going through [this list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9242/24509) to disable some of the services that I do not need on my Fedora desktop. By going through my bash history, I can also see clearly that I have disabled `rsyslog` with the command:

```
# history | grep rsyslog
712  systemctl disable rsyslog
```

And I have not touched `rsyslog` thereafter ever since migrating to journald. I am quite surprise to I see some of the services, that I have disabled a long time ago, being enabled without my knowledge:

```
# systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
nfs-lock.service                   enabled
nfs.target                         enabled
rpcbind.service                    enabled
rsyslog.service                    enabled
```

Does updating disabled services with `yum` re-enable them? If so, is there a good reason for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

No, updating a disabled service with `yum` should not re-enable it.

I suspect however that you never actually stopped the service - doing `systemctl disable` just stops it starting automatically the next time you boot. If the service is already running then it won't stop it - you need to do `systemctl stop` for that.

So if you just disabled it, and you haven't rebooted since, then it will still be running.

Comment: To clarify, I have disabled those services a long time ago (meaning months ago), and it is a desktop which is powered off when not in use.